# Can an intense core/abs workout gives you diarrhea?

Tags: abdominals, core

I follow a pretty intense core/abs workout since 15 days and I have diarrhea since 12-13 days, can it be linked? I mean, does such kind of workout compress so much the bowel that it 'liquify' its 'production'? If so, does it get back to a normal when the core is sufficiently strong? (I have a weak core)

Comment: No, it can't.. if you have diarreah your diet is unhealthy.

Comment: I always have loose stools after an intense ab workout. I wouldn't say diarrhea but definitely not normal. Here's why...
https://www.healthline.com/health/exercise-fitness/diarrhea-after-working-out

Comment: I have IBS and believe me ab exercises mess with my stomach. Diarrhea is so common that I now no longer do them. You can find similar stories on the internet. Some stomachs are more sensitive than others. I'd advise anyone in this situation to ease their workouts and track the symptoms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Diarrhea is a symptom of what's going on *inside* your stomach. Your abdominal muscles are outside, and don't have any effect on your digestive system.

If you have a problem with diarrhea, you should take a second look at what you're eating, as a poor diet is the number one cause of diarrhea.

If you're certain that it's not the diet, see a doctor. You could have an infection like gastroenteritis, which is very annoying and also very contagious.

Comment: Wouldn’t it stand to reason that an intense ab (or cardio) workout could aggravate the digestive system and produce effects such as diarrhea? “Runners Diarrhea” comes to mind.

Comment: @JustSnilloc - No one really knows why runner's diarrhea occurs, but the first suspect is jostling of the stomach. As for ab workouts, this doesn't really do that. You're probably thinking that the ab muscles would "knead" on the stomach, but a) that is extremely minimal and b) it wouldn't disrupt digestion. This is because food is digested by way of stomach acid.

Answer (score 0):

Certain types of exercise cause food to pass through your digestive tract faster than normal. ... It often occurs during or after intense forms of exercise such as running, weightlifting, and cycling. Though it's not convenient, diarrhea connected to working out is relatively normal and usually isn't a cause for concern.